# libmpi_mpifh.so.12: cannot open

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, mpi, lib

I'm trying to run an Atmospheric Model (RegCM) but I've the next error when I try to run an executable

```
./regcmMPI: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_mpifh.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'd trying running commands like:

```
Sudo apt-get install openmpi-dev libopenmpi
```

But I can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`libmpi_mpifh.so.12` is provided by Open MPI v1.10.

Note this version is no more supported.
Open MPI supported versions are currently :

- `v2.1` that provides `libmpi_mpifh.so.20`
- `v3.0` provides `libmpi_mpifh.so.40`

I suggest you first check which version of Open MPI you installed via `apt-get`. If it is `v1.10`, then check where the libs are installed (you might need to set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if the libs are not in a standard location, or use a `module` if your distro support it). If it is a newer version, then your best bet is to recompile your application.