Open MPI Conflicts (BURAI)
I am trying to run SCF calculations in BURAI. I installed BURAI in Ubuntu with this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_V69D-FjGps
When I try to run SCF calculations with this command: /usr/bin/mpirun -np 4 pw.x -in espresso.in, I get this error:
pw.x: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_mpifh.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
pw.x: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_mpifh.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
pw.x: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_mpifh.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
pw.x: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_mpifh.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I found someone with the same problem with a different application here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49418516/20656772
This was the explanation:

libmpi_mpifh.so.12 is provided by Open MPI v1.10.
Note this version is no more supported. Open MPI supported versions are currently :
v2.1 that provides libmpi_mpifh.so.20
v3.0 provides libmpi_mpifh.so.40
I suggest you first check which version of Open MPI you installed via apt-get. If it is v1.10, then check where the libs are installed (you might need to set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH if the libs are not in a standard location, or use a module if your distro support it). If it is a newer version, then your best bet is to recompile your application.

I have a newer version of Open MPI (4.1.2), and I have libmpi_mpifh.so.40 installed, but I don't know how to recompile BURAI (source code here: https://github.com/BURAI-team/burai/tree/master). I tried to reinstall it, but that didn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

my understanding is pw.x is provided by Quantum Espresso and not Burai.
Did you install QE from sources on your system? if not, either rebuild it or run it on a system/container compatible with the one used to build the binaries.

Burai comes with an already compiled pw.x file, but it seems to rely on outdated packages. I decided to just install the quantum-espresso package with apt-get. I am using Burai to create the input files and the quantum-espresso package pw.x file to run the simulations. It works amazingly, and Pranab Das is the GOAT. https://pranabdas.github.io/espresso/setup/install/
